# Constructor alternative for static methods in PHP

Tags: php, static

A few months ago, I have read about a PHP function that is called every time a static method is called, similar to the `__construct` function that is called when an instance of class is instantiated. However, I can't seem to find what function takes care of this functionality in PHP. Is there such a function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can play with [__callStatic()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) and do something like this:

```
class testObj {
  public function __construct() {

  }

  public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments) {
    $name = substr($name, 1);

    if(method_exists("testObj", $name)) {
      echo "Calling static method '$name'<br/>";

      /**
       * You can write here any code you want to be run
       * before a static method is called
       */

      call_user_func_array(array("testObj", $name), $arguments);
    }
  }

  static public function test($n) {
    echo "n * n = " . ($n * $n);
  }
}

/**
 * This will go through the static 'constructor' and then call the method
 */
testObj::_test(20);

/**
 * This will go directly to the method
 */
testObj::test(20);
```

Using this code any method that is preceded by '_' will run the static 'constructor' first.
This is just a basic example, but you can use `__callStatic` however it works better for you.

Good luck!

Comment: It's not what I hoped for, but I think it's the closest to what I am looking for. Thanks, Adi.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method testObj::_test() on line 30
http://codepad.org/Go96TaaS

Answer (score 3):

The __callStatic() is called everytime you call not existing static method of a class.

Comment: I stumbled upon this method in the PHP manual some time ago, but, as you mention, it is only called when a non-existing static method is called.

Answer (score 1):

Could __callStatic() be the method you are referring to?  I just found this in the PHP Manual:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods

Perhaps not, though, since it seems to be a magic method to handle undefined static method calls...

Comment: I'm afraid this is not the method I am looking for. Thanks for your reply.